# Why doesn't /tmp get emptied when symlinked?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

I symlinked /tmp to a second hard drive (the root partition is on an SSD and I want to avoid wear).

Ever since then, it doesn't get emptied on a reboot. Any idea why? I use Ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [bind mount](http://docs.1h.com/Bind_mounts) works.

/etc/fstab contains

```
/path/to/tmp /tmp none bind 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`/tmp` is typically mounted as a [RAM-disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive), so it resets whenever you reboot the machine.  When you symlinked it to a location on a harddrive, the RAM-disk can no longer be mounted at `/tmp` (because the symlink already exists at that path), so  everything written to `/tmp` is stored on your hard drive.  You really should just remove the symlink and let the RAM-disk mount.

Comment: /tmp is not mentioned in fstab, doesn't that mean it's part of the normal filesystem?